# ng-select validate before trigger ngModelChange

Tags: angular, binding

I have a ng-select for a drop down of users. However I want to do some validation like if any pending changes with the current selected user before selecting another user from the dropdown list.

```
<ng-select [items]="users"
           bindLabel="fullName"
           [(ngModel)]="selectedUser"
           (ngModelChange)="setUser($event)"
</ng-select>
```

I put the validation in setUser method, and if there are any pending changes with current user, it will set the selectedUser back to the previous user because this method is called after selectedUser is changed to the next user. However in this case, the display still shows the next user, so binding not reflected on the html, any idea why?

Or is there any way to achieve this? Like using the click method, and cancel the click even so model change won't happen? Thanks

Comment: I don't think that ng-select is able to support such advanced feature. More likely that you need to trace the value before selecting. And my opinion is that your requirement results in a not-good user experience. People may think that something is not working correctly (bug) that he/she selects "B", but the dropdown binds the value that is not what he/she selected. You should provide a label to notify that the user-selected option is not available and suggest the user to re-select another option.

Comment: @YongShun yeah I have a popup dialog to ask if the user want to switch to the new user or stay with the current user if there are any pending changes. But in the current code, I can't switch back to the current user (something to do with binding, but not sure what went wrong there yet).

Comment: Also, you may implement by excluding the data from the `users` to show as option(s), the user cannot pick those invalid options.